# How to hide RecyclerView items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, invisible

I want to hide some of RecyclerView items as shown in the image. When view all is clicked, the layout should expand and remaining items should be visible.

[image: RecyclerView]

There are total of 12 items in the RecyclerView. One row should be hidden.

What I tried was making the items invisible at the beginning and set them to visible when `view all` is clicked by calling a method.

In the adapter I tried this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int i) {
if(i >= 8)
    {
        holder.productName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.product_image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
public void viewAll() {
    //unable to create holder object here
    if(holder.productName.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
    {
        holder.productName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.product_image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}
```

But I am unable to create ViewHolder instance in `view all` method. And also empty spaces are being created where the items are in invisible. Any other techniques which you think is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add variable `int maxCount = 8` and change code to this:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int i) {
        if (i >= maxCount) {
            holder.productName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.product_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

And change `maxCount` on **View All** click;

```
    public void viewAll() {
        maxCount = 12;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. The only problem is the margins are getting messed up.

Comment: I'm glad that it works. Can you provide more details about margins?

Comment: I set `marginBottom` of `view all` as 10dp, but it wasn't working so I had to increase it by 10 to make it work

Comment: I think the recyclerView bottom margin is getting doubled when view is hidden. And also I had to use `View.GONE` instead of `View.INVISIBLE` because it was creating empty spaces.

Comment: @DevSharma `View.INVISIBLE` keeps all your margins and spaces of hidden items, while `View.GONE` removes it. That is why I used `View.GONE` in my snippet of code.

Comment: Yeah thanks. I updated `View.GONE` in my code but forgot to update here

Comment: @DevSharma nice! You can select this answer as `correct` to help other people with the same questions.

Comment: Yeah I was totally going to do that, just trying the other answer. But your answer being the oldest was accepted.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK on Android you can't hide/show items in recycleView (in an optimized way) without changing the item source list. **(I mean dynamically remove/add items in a specific position, start, middle or end of list)**

That said, changing dataSource and refreshing list with that small amount of items is pretty easy and can be done with a simple notifyDataSetChanged

On `Activity/Fragment` instantiate your list with a `class-scoped` variable. I write example in `Activity`, since I don't know if you are using `Activity` or `Fragment`. Obv it will be the same with a `fragment`.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<MyItem> myItems; //or List<MyItem> or whatever


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

        //init everything

        myItems = getVisibleItems(); //create a method that returns the visible items, based on your logics. You can also avoid creating a method and simply retrieve items; as you prefer.

        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(MyActivity.this, myItems);
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MyActivity.this));
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    }
    //other stuffs
}
```

Then, whenever you want to change your list items, just update your `ArrayList` (**or list, or whatever**) and notify the adapter that something changed.

```
private void updateList(){
    myItems = getVisibleItems();
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Note: you don't have to copy the list in the adapter, use the same as you pass, i.e:

```
ArrayList<MyItems> adapterSource = null;
//constructor
public MyAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<MyItems> items){
    //other stuff
    this.adapterSource = items;
}
```

Note, I wrote this by hand without a compiler, it might not be perfect.

Let me know if that helped!

Comment: I am getting the image and text from backend so maybe it would be a heavy process.

Comment: @DevSharma you can store them into a list in your activity and pass only the visible ones to the adapter. for example you can create a list named "originalSource", and another list named "visibleSource" (for example). Then you fill visibleSource in your getVisibleItems method and pass them to the adapter

Comment: I might have written it in a confusing way, tell me if it's unclear

Comment: So do I have to set the adapter again?

Comment: you just have to change the adapter item source and call notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: I'll try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

define local variable

```
var Int count = 8
```

display, as in your code

in `viewAll` method set `count = 12`, and refresh adapter via listener for activity